# Full width div browser resize issue

Tags: html, css, resize

I have a div with 100% width, which fills the screen (horz) fine, but when I manually resize the browser window (horizontally) until it hits my fixed width wrapper (so scrollbar appears) and then scroll to the right the 100% width div does not fit 100% any more. Probably sounds more complicated than it is.

Example here : [link](http://s169332309.websitehome.co.uk/fullwidth_issue.html)

Comment: Which browser are you using. No issue with Chrome. @chris-carruthers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `min-width` of the page body to the same width as your fixed width wrapper, for example:

```
body {
    min-width: 900px;
}
```

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/XLHqN/

Comment: That's awesome man you nailed it. ( still not 100% sure why that works ;) Cheers. I've uploaded the fixed version to that link now for reference.